# Convert Binary Data Stored as ASCII to Binary

Tags: shell, binary, tr

I've got a load of binary data stored as ASCII text in a file like this:

```
0b 0000 0001
0b 0000 0000
0b 1111 0001 
etc
```

How would I convert this to a raw binary bitstream, and save it to disk?

Can this be done with standard unix tools?

Comment: So binary representation (not hexadecimal), with one byte per line, a space between the nibbles and a prefix of "0x " ?

Comment: "0b" not "0x" that was a typo. But yeah, binary representation

Comment: It is possible to generate this output with `xxd -c 1 -b | sed 's/^[0-9a-f]*:/0b/' | cut -f 1-2 -d\ ` but xxd doesn't support `-b` with `-r` :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have not fully fleshed this out but try the following:

```
$ cat demo.sh
#!/bin/bash

while read bb nibble1 nibble2
do
    byte=$(printf "%s%s" ${nibble1} ${nibble2} )
    hexstr=$(printf '\\\\x%02x' $((2#${byte})) )
    eval printf "$hexstr"
done < infile > outfile
```

Using your sample input:

```
$ ./demo.sh

$ xxd outfile
00000000: 0100 f1                                  ...
$
```